# Code successfully running but returning an empty dataframe

Tags: python, html

I found this code written from a few years ago, I wanted to implement it to scrap data from OpenTable since I am a beginner with web scraping. Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
import re

def parse_html(html):
    data, item = pd.DataFrame(), {}
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    for i, resto in enumerate(soup.find_all('div', class_='rest-row-info')):
        item['name'] = resto.find('span', class_='rest-row-name-text').text

        booking = resto.find('div', class_='booking')
        item['bookings'] = re.search('\d+', booking.text).group() if booking else 'NA'

        rating = resto.select('.star-rating .star-rating-score')
        #print(rating)
        item['rating'] = rating[0]['aria-label'] if rating else 'NA'

        reviews = resto.find('span', class_='star-rating-text--review-text')
        
        reviews = resto.select('div.review-rating-text span')
        print(reviews)
        item['reviews'] = reviews[0].text if reviews else 'NA'

        item['price'] = int(resto.find('div', class_='rest-row-pricing').find('i').text.count('$'))
        
        item['cuisine'] = resto.find_all('span', class_='rest-row-meta--cuisine')[-1].text
        #print(item['cuisine'])
        
        item['location'] = resto.find('span', class_='rest-row-meta--location').text
        data[i] = pd.Series(item)
    return data.T


restaurants = pd.DataFrame()
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.opentable.com/s?dateTime=2022-11-15T19%3A00%3A00&covers=2&metroId=21&regionIds%5B0%5D=251&neighborhoodIds%5B0%5D=&term=&originCorrelationId=e1dada45-cc11-4711-848f-825e79b3ef30"
driver.get(url)

while True:
    sleep(1)
    new_data = parse_html(driver.page_source)
    if new_data.empty:
        break
    restaurants = pd.concat([restaurants, new_data], ignore_index=True)
    print(len(restaurants))
   # driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()
    
#driver.close()
restaurants.to_csv('results.csv', index=False)
print(restaurants)
```

The code successfully runs but it is returning an empty Data Frame:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Can someone please advise what is wrong and how I can fix it?

I've been researching solutions but having found much on how to fix it.

Comment: If your code was written years ago there are chances that the page design has changed (maybe just for the design or to prevent scraping) and that you'll have to change the scraping method, searching for new tags, ...
Open your url and look at the source code if css class always match or download it and grep. I can't find any "rest-row" string.

Comment: Thanks for this. While I was inspecting the html on the page, I wasn't seeing rest-row string either.

Answer (score 0):

**Wrong Tag or missing tag**

Your code *item* is empty because the code can not locate the tag you pass in your BeautifulSoup library. Inspect the browser and confirm if the tag is available.

Example of the tag is:

```
soup.find_all('div', class_='rest-row-info')):
```